# singularize noun phrases with spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy, chunks, lemmatization

I am looking for a way to singularize noun chunks with spacy

```
S='There are multiple sentences that should include several parts and also make clear that studying Natural language Processing is not difficult '
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(S)

[chunk.text for chunk in doc.noun_chunks]
# = ['an example sentence', 'several parts', 'Natural language Processing']
```

You can also get the "root" of the noun chunk:

```
[chunk.root.text for chunk in doc.noun_chunks]
# = ['sentences', 'parts', 'Processing']
```

I am looking for a way to singularize those roots of the chunks.

GOAL: Singulirized: ['sentence', 'part', 'Processing']

Is there any obvious way? Is that always depending on the POS of every root word?

Thanks

note:
I found this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nlp-singularizing-plural-nouns-and-swapping-infinite-phrases/
but that approach looks to me that leads to many many different methods and of course different for every language. ( I am working in EN, FR, DE)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272958/finding-the-pos-of-the-root-of-a-noun-chunk-with-spacy) you asked yesterday?

Comment: Hi @bivouac0 no it isnt. one is about finding POS (Part of speech) and the other one about converting a token or noun phrase into singular. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the basic form of each word, you can use ".lemma_" property of chunk or token property

I use Spacy version 2.x

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable=['parser', 'ner'])
doc = nlp('did displaying words')
print (" ".join([token.lemma_ for token in doc]))
```

and the output :

```
do display word
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There is! You can take the lemma of the head word in each noun chunk.

```
[chunk.root.lemma_ for chunk in doc.noun_chunks]                       
Out[82]: ['sentence', 'part', 'processing']
```